# Best workaround for Firestore's limitation of the range filter and orderBy on the same field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement pagination while filtering the documents based on an expiration date and ordering them by a creation date. As you may know, Cloud Firestore has the limitation that the range filter and orderBy must be on the same field. So, my code below is apparently invalid:

```
posts
  .where("expiredAt", ">", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp())
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .startAt(date)
  .limit(10);
```

I know this has been asked and answered here multiple times. However, the solutions suggested by the Firebase team or others are not satisfying and efficient. Filtering/ordering on client side is not a good practice for big applications. Besides, most people want to keep the number of queries and the load of data as low as possible.

In my case, I have to skip the expired documents and show the last created documents first. I also have to paginate the data to avoid unnecessary reads. Has anyone had a similar problem and found out a different way around from what has already been said?

Comment: If you're asking the same question that's already been asked, Stack Overflow would suggest that this be closed as a duplicate.  If there are better solutions, they are expected to appear as answers in the other questions, even if the OP already marked an accepted answer (which does happen very commonly).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your reply. Technically, I'm not asking the same question. The root of the problem is same for all questions that have been asked, but the solutions might differ based on people's expectations.

Comment: To be honest, it's hard to tell where your expectations are different.  Please edit the question to differentiate your specific problem in a way that's clearly different from questions whose answer you don't like.  I don't think it's enough to just "dislike" the answer in order to propose yet another question.